# Any idea how to align this bootstrap content?

Tags: bootstrap-4

First time here and i'm honestly discouraged haha.
I'm doing a Web Dev class and we are learning bootstrap. I'm stuck here. I just cannot understand how to put the content in the rectangle where the arrow points.

I'm pretty sure it's a simple thing, but right now even with tutorials i'm stuck at the beginning of the code.

If you guys have any idea or tips. We have to reproduce a linkedin page  and i'm stuck right at the start.

thank you ;-;

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <ul>
                <h1>Gérer mon réseau</h1>
                <li><a href="#">Relation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Personnes que je suis</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Événements</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hashtag</a></li>
            </ul>
            <img src="image1.jpg">
            <p> Développez votre réseau</p>
            Infos &nbsp;&nbsp; Accessibilité
            Assistance clientèle
            Conditions générales et confidentialité
            Préférences Pubs &nbsp;&nbsp; Publicité
            Solutions professionnelles
            Téléchargez l'application Linkedin Plus
            <br>
            Linked IN Linedin corporation 2022
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Ines H</h3>
            <p>Web Developper</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Ines H</h3>
            <p>Web Developper</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Ines H</h3>
            <p>Web Developper</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Ines H</h3>
            <p>Web Developper</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

[What i'd like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU6Qx.jpg)

[The final result we need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxktz.jpg)